# How to send "wall" like message to other logged in users from C++

Tags: c++, ipc

I'm writing some software that will run as a daemon on an embedded platform without a screen.  Since the daemon can be stopped by a user who is logged in (via ssh), I would like to inform the logged in user(s), that the daemon has been successfully terminated.  I could use a script, employing `wall` or `write` to do this, and call it from my C++ program using `execve` but I'm wondering if there is a C++ way of doing this which does not require `libnotify` (which I gather is for GUI oriented environments) and is not available on the platform I'm developing for.

Comment: embedded linux system?

Comment: Have you considered reading [wall](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/wall.c) source code? I would go with just `system("wall ...");`. You can just reinwent the weel and write your own code and copy all the  `ttymsg` and `wall.c` source code with proper `open`, `writev` and `getutxent` error code and compabilitiy handling. Or just call `wall`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  Yes, the system is based on Gentoo linux and I am unable to use `portage` to add to the code base.  Only problem with `wall` is that the banner can only be suppressed by the root user.  (But I suppose I can call it using `sudo`.)